# Is there a single-input, binary output stdlib or boost function I can bind to?

Tags: c++, boost

```
bool all_ok = boost::algorithm::all_of(info.begin(), threadInfo.end(), [&](std::pair<std::string, Info> const &p){ return p.second.am_ok; });
```

Above is a line I am trying to remove c++11 from (in order to be compliant with an application I am integrating with, if you must know). I would like to replace the lambda without defining a function external to the current method.

My question is, how can I utilize boost::bind to represent a function & binding that takes in a single input and returns a boolean?

Comment: What about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372695/is-there-a-standard-c-function-object-for-taking-apart-a-stdpair (to replace part of the lambda, there's still more to go all the way)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `boost::bind` to do this, it would look something like this:

```
boost::bind(&Info::am_ok, boost::bind(&std::pair<std::string, Info>::second, _1));
```

Boost.Bind supports composition of its function objects, so in this case the function object created by the nested `bind` gets called first, and its result (the `Info` object) is passed to the enclosing function object, which returns the `am_ok` member of the structure.

You see that the code is somewhat contrived, so you'll probably want to write a custom function object anyway.

```
struct is_ok
{
    typedef bool result_type;
    result_type operator() (std::pair<std::string, Info> const &p) const
    {
        return p.second.am_ok;
    }
};
```